# Rails - Individual Sections for Each Object?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

So in my current rails app, I am working on allowing to user to create activities as well as categories. The categories act somewhat similar to folders to where the user can use them to sort activities.

The difficulty I am experiencing is not having any idea how to implement this with HTML. I know you can print out the names of each category or activity in the database using an "each" loop. I am using a Bootstrap stylesheet and it has a "collapse" class that I plan to use to implement categories.

However in order to use the "collapse" class, it requires a "href" to a panel that it will toggle to show/hide. When this is attempted using an "each" loop, the result is that the category names will be printed out with the "collapse" as the data toggle but each category would reference the same panel. This means that I cannot list the activities belonging to each category as they would each only toggle show/hide a single shared panel.

I apologize if I am using incorrect wording to describe the issue I am having but here are some [pictures to show what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avtsA.jpg)

The issue within the pictures can easily be fixed if I had two different panels within the "each" loop and creating two instances of the "collapse" data toggle to link them to the corresponding panels. However, this is a temporary fix as when the user is allowed to create multiple categories, I will need to create individual panels for each category to reference.

Basically, I need to be able to create individual panels for each set of activities belonging to a common category and then link each of those panels to the corresponding activity. With my limited knowledge on HTML and Rails, I can't think of a solution to this or how to approach this. Any help or advice would be much appreciated, thanks

Category Display Code:

```
<body>
<div class="panel-body">
  <h2 align = "center">Categories</h2>
</div>
<% @categories.each do |cat| %>
    <div class="panel-group">
      <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel text-center">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
                <%= cat.c_name %>
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Activity One</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Activity Two</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Activity Three</li>
          </ul>
          <div class="panel-footer">Activities</div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use unique ids which you should do anyway when you use id in HTML.

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
```

The problem with this line is that it is hard coded it has to be dynamic:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse<%= cat.id%>">
```

This way, each toggle href has a unique id based on the object's id column.

You would also have to change this line:

```
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

to the same:

```
<div id="collapse<%= cat.id %>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

Comment: I had no idea you could to this. Thanks for the help!